# Disable/Hide download button in react-documents npm

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, npm

I am using `#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0` in react-documents url for disabling toolbar but it doesn't work.

```
<DocumentViewer
    style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
    queryParams="hl=eg"
    url={fileurl+"#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0"}
    viewer="google"
    overrideLocalhost="https://react-doc-viewer.firebaseapp.com/"
></DocumentViewer>
```

anyone, please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#pdf-download {
```

display: none;
}

this can hide your download button